# Pipe assigns variable

Tags: bash, variable

For simplicity I would like to do:

```
echo cart | assign spo;
echo $spo
```

Output: cart

Does such an `assign` application exist?

I am aware of all the ways to do this using substitution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without substitution?

Comment: I like the reverse Polish notation flow when writing with pipes only. I am much faster coding and the codes quality / speed is not so important. Also I don't when chaining it is hella easier to comment out parts of the chain and echo the current output rather then erase ticks etc.

Comment: If you're concerned about ease of debugging, consider putting the backticks command on a series of separate lines. `A=$( some | command | here )` with each of `some |`, `command |`, and `here` on its own line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
echo cart | { IFS= read -r spo; printf '%s\n' "$spo"; }
```

Would work (store the output of `echo` without the trailing newline character into the `spo` variable) as long as `echo` outputs only one line.

You could always do:

```
assign() {
  eval "$1=\$(cat; echo .); $1=\${$1%.}"
}
assign spo < <(echo cart)
```

The following solutions would work in `bash` scripts, but not at the `bash` prompt:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
echo cat | assign spo
```

Or:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
whatever | IFS= read -rd '' spo
```

To store the output of `whatever` up to the first NUL characters (`bash` variables can't store NUL characters anyway) in `$spo`.

Or:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
whatever | readarray -t spo
```

to store the output of `whatever` in the `$spo` *array* (one line per array element).

Comment: shouldn't there be a space between `IFS=` and `read`?

Comment: All hail last pipe . Also side note set +m ( ermmm or -m ) is needed from a command line she'll as last pipe does not work with job control active .

Answer (score 18):

You could do something like this, if you use `bash`:

```
echo cart | while read spo; do echo $spo; done
```

Unfortunately, variable "spo" won't exist outside of the while-do-done loop. If you can get what you want done inside the while-loop, that will work.

You can actually do almost exactly what you wrote above in ATT ksh (not in pdksh or mksh) or in the fabulous zsh:

```
% echo cart | read spo
% echo $spo
cart
```

So, another solution would be to use ksh or zsh.

Comment: You can use coprocesses in the Korn Shell (e.g. `mksh`): `echo cart |& while read -p spo; do echo $spo; done` (actually better to use `while IFS= read -p -r spo; do…` though)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the issue correctly you want to pipe stdout to a variable.
At least that was what I was looking for and ended up here. So for those who share my fate:

```
spa=$(echo cart)
```

Assigns `cart` to the variable `$spa`.

Comment: That's what they call substitution, which the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: This was useful to me, i just needed to assign it to a variable, i didn't care how it got there!

Comment: The shell does indeed pipe the output of the command to the variable.
It ALSO pipes  stdin into the command.
This can mess up while loops that read input, and cause them to exhaust stdin and quit reading after one loop. This is a baffling situation -- no error occurs and no indication of what is the matter is exported.

You must explicitly redirect stdin from /dev/null to prevent the loop from stopping at one iteration.

out=$( prog </dev/null  arg1 arg2 ...)  # does the trick.  

Just putting this here to be stumbled upon someday and make someone's day.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output the current pipe stream use `cat`.

```
echo cart | cat
```

If you want to continue your command chain, try using the `tee` command to echo the output.

```
echo cart | tee /dev/tty | xargs ls
```

You could use an alias to shorten the command.

```
alias tout='tee /dev/tty'
echo cart | tout | xargs ls
```

Comment: Why would you want to pipe output to a plain `cat`?

Comment: @roaima Some command recognize they are running on a terminal an behave differently than if they are outputting to a pipe. In particular they may truncate lines to the current screen width. For most command the cat command is redundant.

Comment: Ah ok, I see now what you were trying to illustrate. The `echo | cat` construct threw me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution to the problem.

```
# assign will take last line of stdout and create an environment variable from it
# notes: a.) we avoid functions so that we can write to the current environment
#        b.) aliases don't take arguments, but we write this so that the "argument" appears
#            behind the alias, making it appear as though it is taking one, which in turn
#            becomes an actual argument into the temporary script T2.
# example: echo hello world | assign x && echo %x outputs "hello world"
alias assign="tail -1|tee _T1>/dev/null&&printf \"export \\\$1=\$(cat _T1)\nrm _T*\">_T2&&. _T2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a temporary file you can avoid substitution *and* the expensive pipe.

```
echo cart > tmp.$$; read spo < tmp.$$; rm tmp.$$
```

Fun shell fact: you can even move the redirection operator to the front for improved "pipe" feeling:

```
echo cart > tmp.$$; < tmp.$$ read spo
```